# Phantom wallet google plugin missing

Tags: mobile-wallet-adapter

I use the same Google account for the browsers of two computers. There is a phantom wallet on the old computer (no private key backup). When I used the old computer today, it automatically synchronized the plug-in data of the new computer and deleted my phantom wallet plug-in. Is there any way I can get my original data back?

Comment: It might be better to ask Phantom support directly, they'll likely provide the best answer